# How to encrypt a guid into equal length string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, guid

I need to encrypt a guid and the encrypted string length should be 32 char max, not more than that. Please suggest me an encryption method available in C# for that.

I was using AES in CFB mode, as in [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7546/A-CBC-Stream-Cipher-in-C-With-wrappers-for-two-ope), but that is producing 64 char long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a GUID is inherently 16 bytes of data... so that's what you should encrypt. That's a single block in AES. As per Reid's comment, the exact size of the output will depend on how you've configured things, but to convert the result into text, you'll probably want to use base64 if you need ASCII text with a fairly minimal size.

Base64 allows you to use 24 bytes to produce a 32 character result - so you should try different padding/cipher modes until you find one where the output is 24 bytes or less, if this 32 character requirement is a "hard" one (and you need ASCII; if you don't need ASCII then there's a lot more room to play...)

Comment: The size of the output depends on the cipher mode and padding mode chosen. Some cipher modes may prepend/append an IV to the ciphertext (depending on their implementation), and some padding modes will pad one full block into two (for instance, the most popular, PKCS#7, does this).

Comment: Thanks Jon and Reid for the quick response. I am currently working on this.

Answer (score 2):

If a GUID is 16 bytes (I'll take that as a given) then you can simply do a single AES ECB mode encrypt *without padding* of the plaintext (i.e. the GUID). This comes down to performing a single block encrypt as indicated [in the answer of Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996694/589259). You can then convert to hexadecimals. That will with 100% certainty result in a 32 character result.

Note that ECB does not use an IV, which means that you can distinguish different GUID's from each other (as each GUID will be mapped to exactly one ciphertext). But the ciphertext should otherwise simply be identical to the security of the used block cipher and key.

```
public class EncryptGUI
{
    private Aes aes;

    public EncryptGUI (byte[] key)
    {
        aes = Aes.Create ();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        aes.Key = key;
    }

    public String encryptUID (byte[] guid)
    {
        ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor ();
        byte[] result = aesDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock (guid, 0, guid.Length);
        return ToHex (result);
    }

    public static string ToHex (byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder (data.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in data)
            hex.AppendFormat ("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString ();
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        EncryptGUI main = new EncryptGUI (key);

        byte[] guid = new byte[16];
        Console.Out.WriteLine (main.encryptUID (guid));
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the GUID is 32 bytes

Comment: Are you sure it is not 32 *characters*? The actual content may still be just 16 bytes. If you encrypt that and encode it back to a GUID... Hmm, I should probably include encoding / decoding in above, but my dev enviroment is on my old laptop... still converting to 64 bit and a new laptop.